# How to create pop up window with ASP:MENU and xmlDataSource for certain menu item only?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to update current application Menu.
It's using ASP:MENU with xmlDataSource.

I tried to used MenuItemClick event so that when users click on certain menu items, it would pop up in new window. The sad thing is the event only triggered when I click on the menu, not the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this.

```
protected void Menu1_MenuItemDataBound(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.Text == "MenuItemName")
    {
        e.Item.Target = "_blank";            
    }
}
```